# yii combine model relation

Tags: yii, relationship

I'd like to know how (if it's possible) to combine (union) relations in a Yii model.

I have the following models:

- User
- Country
- Province
- City
- Item

The geographic hierarchy relationship is:

- Country has many Provinces
- Province has many Cities
- City has many Items

Country and Province level has many items: 'through'=>'cities'

The user-geographic relationship is a bit more complex:

- User - Country (Many to Many)
- User - Province (Many to Many)
- User - City (Many to Many)

So a user can be assigned to any Geographic Level and will have implied assignment to all of that level's child levels.

eg. A user assigned to Canada, California and Chicago, will have access to:

- All items in all provinces in all cities in Canada
- as well as all items in all cities in California
- as well as all items in Chicago

As such I would like to see which items are assigned to a user through their Geographic levels. So I would like to set up a relation that will allow me to access all items assigned to them simply by accessing the "items" property (eg. $myUser->items).

Effectively I would like to combine these into a single relation called "items":

```
'countryItems' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Item', array('id' => 'country_id'), 'through'=>'countries'),
'provinceItems' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Item', array('id' => 'province_id'), 'through'=>'provinces'),
'cityItems' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Item', array('id' => 'city_id'), 'through'=>'cities'),
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is, that you can not create a SQL statement that gets all distinct items of  a user for you because your connections between Items and Users are ambiguous: One Item can be connected over different paths to a User. That means, there could even be more than one connection for the same Item to a User (e.g. via a City and via a Province).

You could try to add a `JOIN` for every possible path between a User and an item (through Country, Province and City). But the mentioned ambiguity will always be in your way: You can end up with a result, that contains duplicates.

And since there's no solution in raw SQL you can not solve it with Yii relations alone. You can always write a getter, though:

```
public getItems()
{
    $items = array();

    foreach($this->countryItems as $item)
        $items[$item->id] = $item;

    foreach($this->provinceItems as $item)
        $items[$item->id] = $item;

    foreach($this->cityItems as $item)
        $items[$item->id] = $item;

    return $items;
}
```

This effectively gives you a `$items` property that contains all distinct items for that user.